# HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error Handler "aspNetCore" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

im managing a website written in asp.net core 3.1. I published website on subdomain but then I encountered such an error "HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error Handler "aspNetCore" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list".I contacted the server company but I've been waiting for a week and still problem not solved.